# Add dynamically components in vue.js not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try to add dynamically component. This component set into props. 
I not register components into `components:{}` section, because I don't now how many components and their name will be send from props.
I use ES6 syntax, where import js modules not work into `ready(){}` section.
My code:

```js
let Child = Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {
     msg: 'CHILDREN'
    }
  },
  template: '<div class="c-child">component {{msg}}</div>'
})


let Parent = Vue.extend({
 props: {
   component: ''
  },
  data() {
    return {
     msg: 'PARENT'
    }
  },
  template: '<div class="c-parent">from component- {{msg}}<br><component :is="component"/></div>',
})

// register
Vue.component('parent-component', Parent)

// create a root instance
let vue = new Vue({
  el: '#root'
})
```

```css
.c-parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.c-child {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.common.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <parent-component :component="Child"></parent-component>
</div>
```

Dynamic component not render:

```
<component :is="component"/>
```

P.S. This code work on jsfiddle - [open link](https://jsfiddle.net/slavik_210/ww3w405c/31/)

Comment: @gurghet are you saying you don't understand his english? If that is the case, then try to at least understand what he is saying in essence, or ask for clarification in the comments. Your comment is really not useful in any way.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample fiddle!

Comment: Yes, [link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/slavik_210/ww3w405c/31/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the interpreted component name to `:is=""` component, defining them the following way should work:

```
import GroupsGrid from './../../components/groups'
import RolesGrid from './../../components/roles'
import MainTabs from './../../components/main-tabs.vue' // <-- this component will be render other components

    data: {
        tabs: {
            'GroupsGrid': 'groups-grid',
            'RolesGrid': 'roles-grid'
        }
    },
```

And still used like this

```
<component :is="tabs.GroupsGrid"></component>
```